# How to set a direct message in the .ini file in OMNeT++?

Tags: server, ide, router, omnet++, inet

I've been using OMNeT++ for a week, I'm still learning.
I'm learning it as university homework, and I have to send some data about a router from the router itself to a host. In other words, I have to notify a server of the router status.

My professor told me maybe I can use the module called Probe to collect data.
I thought of using the RadioMedium in order to be able to send the data from the router to the Probe, and linking the probe to the server.
But all of this seems useless given that I could use the wlan interfaces of the two nodes (and given that the probe has no gates).

Searching on the web I found that I could use Direct Messages, and I wondered if I could implement a direct message from router to server in the .ini file.

I'd like to know how to do it in details. If that's not the right approach, I don't know what else to do.
I'd prefer not to change the C++ files, as I don't know how to program and even the professor told me to not change the C++ files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In OMNeT++ models, different aspects of the system are specified by different files:

- INI files are used to specify **parameters and configuration**
- NED files are used to specify **topology** of the network (and the internals of nodes)
- C++ files are used to specify the **behavior** of the different modules

The thing, you want to achieve (sending some specific data to a host from a router, and I guess also receiving at the host and processing it (otherwise, what's the point?)) is clearly a **behavior**, so you have to write C++ code.

Most likely you have to write an UDP application, that is installed in both the router and the host and they talk to each other using UDP packets.

Comment: That's a really clear answer, thank you a lot! Do you know how to write something like this? Or can you point to me resources to learn how to code an application like that in omnet++?
I searched online and I found I may have to use direct messages or signals, but I'm not familiar with C++.

Comment: Without having a minimal experience with C++ and the toolchain, you will have a hard time to implement any behavior in INET. It's not impossible, but it will be slow. What you are suggesting like "direct messages" or "signals" has nothing to do with this problem. Those are much lower level concepts. What you have to do is to implement something like the `UdpBasicApp` in INET (i.e. your so called Probe module would be an 'application' module in fact) and you have to install that application inside the `StandardHost` (and the sending app in the switch).

Comment: I've thought of modifying the UdpBasicApp.cc file too. I'm thinking of inserting a self message which everytime is received makes the UdpBasicApp send a packet containing the info. Is this a suitable approach?
Also, how can I make the UdpBasicApp get that info from lower "levels"? My packet (message to be sent to the server) needs to contain info about the buffer, so the UdpBasicApp should get info from other modules lower in the hierarchy.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could help me with this, I'm pretty stuck